# Getting the navigation goal from RVIZ

Tags: navigation, kinect, pose, rviz, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to get the initial pose of my turtlebot using :

`rospy.wait_for_message('initialpose', PoseWithCovarianceStamped)`

`rospy.Subscriber('initialpose', PoseWithCovarianceStamped)`

This allows me to get a the initial pose when a user clicks sets the 2d Pose estimate in RVIZ. My question is threefold

- How do I achieve the same with the 2d Navigation Goal (getting it fom RVIZ)?
- What message should  I wait for and subscribe to?
- What TYPE of message am I looking for? For example with initialpose I get a PoseWithCovarianceStamped message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196593/getting-the-navigation-goal-from-rviz/) by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz publishes goals on the topic /move_base_simple/goal as a geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-03**:
The specific topic can be changed using the Tool Properties panel.

**Comment by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on 2014-11-25**:
@David thanks got it. Do you know how I can now convert this to a goal coordinate. Im not having any luck

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-25**:
What do you mean by goal coordinate?

**Comment by [Giza](https://answers.ros.org/users/19792/giza/) on 2014-11-26**:
Sorry about that. How do I convert the PoseStamped to  MoveBaseGoal() if at all possible?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-28**:
If you look at http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_msgs you'll see that all MoveBaseGoal contains is a PoseStamped.